# How to select unique lines based on the column of another file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have 2 genetic datasets. File1 is a txt file and has chromosome IDs which all also appear in file 2. File 2 is a csv file and is bigger than file 1 and has more unique chromosome IDs. How can I extract only the lines in file 2 which have unique chromosome IDs in comparison to file 1?

For example my data looks like this:

File 1 (chromosome position is actually my 125th column, implied by the ...):

```
Gene  pval    ... Chromosome position ID
ACE   0.002   ... 01:3290834_CT_C_1
NOS   0.01    ... 03:3304593_GA_G_1
BRCA  0.004 . ... 06:6265733_GA_G_1
CYP3  0.34    ... 09:9433933_GA_G_1
```

File 2 (chromosome position is my first column):

```
Chromosome position ID  Gene  pval
01:1243933_GA_G_1       ACE   0.002
03:3304593_GA_G_1       NOS   0.01
06:6265733_GA_G_1       BRCA  0.004
09:9433933_GA_G_1       CYP3  0.34
```

Based only on the chromosome position ID, the output unique line(s) which only appear in file 2 would be:

```
Chromosome position ID  Gene  pval
01:1243933_GA_G_1       ACE   0.002
```

I've tried to get this output with `uniq` and `sort` but currently I'm only finding examples online which use multiple text files but want the opposite where they take the matching ID lines not the unique ID lines. I have also tried `grep` but with these files being large the command is killed.

Comment: is this ask the same exercise you already asked in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564514/how-to-select-and-extract-matching-data-using-awk

Comment: Same data but instead of matching I am trying to find the unique values. Currently been trying to use that match finding code to apply to unique values only but I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Adaption of the solution in your other thread (excluding the shell expansion file[12]):

```
awk ' FNR==NR {P[$125]; next} FNR==1 || !($1 in P)' file1 file2
Chromosome position ID  Gene  pval
01:1243933_GA_G_1       ACE   0.002
```

Comment: Thank you for this, at the moment it produces an empty file - one file is a csv and one is a txt file, would that cause this?

Comment: What is `csv` if not text? Don't your sample data represent the real data?